# VBA, Find MIN value, Highlight row based on this value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of values, I want to find the MIN, then highlight the row of this Min value.

```
Sub worstcase()


Set Rng = .Range("H44:H54")
worstcase = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng)
Debug.Print worstcase
```

How can I highlight rows based on variable worstcase? 
I have my static range, and find the min value, but now I need to highlight the row of the worstcase variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Highlight Row With Found Criteria

The code is highlighting each row where the minimum was found. Use Exit For to highlight only the first found.

### The Code

```
Sub worstcase()

    Dim worstcase As Double ' Long for whole numbers.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("H44:H54")
        worstcase = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
        Debug.Print worstcase

        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = worstcase Then
                cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Hightlight whole row.
                'cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 ' Hightlight only cell.
                'Exit For ' To highlight only the first found row.
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

### EDIT:

```
Sub worstcase()

    Const cFirst As Variant = "H"
    Const cLast As Variant = "Q"

    Dim worstcase As Double ' Long for whole numbers.
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .Range("H44:H54")
        worstcase = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
        Debug.Print worstcase

        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = worstcase Then
                .Range(.Cells(cell.Row, cFirst), .Cells(cell.Row, cLast)) _
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Hightlight cells.
                'Exit For ' To highlight only the first found cells.
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a highlight specified range option? ie Still only using the min value , instead of entirerow, highlight H to Q ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it thus.

Won't work though if you have a repeated minimum.

Also you could use conditional formatting and avoid VBA.

```
Sub worstcase()

Dim Rng As Range, worstcase, i As Long

Set Rng = Range("H44:H54")

With Rng
    worstcase = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells)
    i = Application.Match(worstcase, .Cells, 0)
    .Cells(i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! and if I dont want to do entire row, say I want to highlight a range based on the min, say H Min to Q Min?

Comment: Update the range. `.Range(.Cells(i,8), .Cells(i,17)).Interior.Color = vbRed`

Answer (score 1):

Create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula.

```
=$H44=min($H$44:$H$54)
```

This VBA will create a CFR for rows 44:54.

```
With worksheets("sheet1").range("44:54")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$H44=min($H$44:$H$54)"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = vbred
End With
```